# How to get gulp-jshint to ignore folders

Tags: gulp, jshint, jscs, gulp-jscs, gulp-jshint

I have the following folder structure within a solution that I have inherited

```
.\gulp.config.js
.\gulpfile.js
.\.jscsrc
.\.jshintrc
.\default.js
.\Resources\js\main.js
.\Resources\js\modules\   various user created js files
.\Resources\js\vendor\    various js files i.e jQuery
```

I have installed gulp-jscs and gulp-jshint.

The .jscsrc I have taken from https://github.com/johnpapa/pluralsight-gulp/blob/master/.jscsrc.

I have the following within gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict'

var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var jscs = require('gulp-jscs');

gulp.task('verifyJS',function(){
    gulp.src([
        './Resources/**/*.js',
        './*.js'
    ])
    .pipe(jscs())
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', { verbose: true }));
});
```

I am trying to update the excludeFiles within .jscsrc to exclude the following:

```
.\default.js 
.\resources\js\vendor
```

This is what I have tried:

```
 "excludeFiles": [
     "node_modules/**",
     "bower_components/**",
     "Resources/js/vendor/**", // vendor supplied files. ie jQuery
     "./Resources/js/vendor/**", 
     "default.js", 
     "/default.js", 
     "./default.js", 
 ],
```

I have included all the combinations that I have tried.

But when i run `gulp verifyJS` it is still including the files that I want to exclude.

How do I correctly set `excludeFiles`  to exclude the file within the root of the project and the subfolder with all subsequent files and folders?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gulp-jshint` doesn't care what's in your `.jscsrc` since that is the config file for `gulp-jscs`. You need a [`.jshintignore`](http://jshint.com/docs/cli/#ignoring-files) file instead.

Here's how to ignore your vendor files in both `gulp-jscs` and `gulp-jshint`:

**.jscsrc**

```
"excludeFiles": [
  "node_modules/**",
  "bower_components/**",
  "Resources/js/vendor/**",
  "default.js", 
],
```

**.jshintignore**

```
node_modules/**
bower_components/**
Resources/js/vendor/**
default.js
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('verifyJS', function(){
  return gulp.src([
    './Resources/**/*.js',
    './*.js'
  ])
  .pipe(jscs())
  .pipe(jscs.reporter()) // you forgot this
  .pipe(jshint())
  .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', { verbose: true }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had really gone down the wrong rabbit hole. Everything works now